# Using Javascript to click button

Tags: javascript, safari, applescript

I made an AppleScript to access a webpage and login. Well, at some point I need to click on a button to valid my vote.
Here is what I get on that button :

```
 <form method="post" action="/website/in/16">
 <input type="submit" name="valid" value="Valider mon vote" class="btn btn-default" />
```

I thought it'd be easy to do it with Javascript, here is my code :

```
tell application "Safari"
    do JavaScript "document.getElementsByName('valid').click();"
end tell
```

A click on the link to vote opens a webpage into the existing one, does it change anything for my problem?

Answer (score 2):

You have to specify the document that the JavaScript should be evaluated in.

```
do JavaScript "document.readyState" in document 1
```

Now it's evaluated in the frontmost tab of the frontmost window.
A safe way would be something like this:

```
tell application "Safari"
    do JavaScript "document.getElementsByName('valid').click();" in item 1 of (every tab of every window whose URL starts with "http://www.votepage.com/")
end tell
```

Now it will work even if the tab is in the background (or Safari is not the frontmost application).

Comment: It appears that you do indeed have to specify a tab, despite Safari's AppleScript dictionary suggesting that the tab spec. is _optional_ (as of OS X 10.9.2).

Comment: Thanks for the hint and the correction. I've updated it.

Comment: Actually, I was _agreeing_ with you. :) The dictionary states that you specify the target as a _tab_ object, but it appears that you can use a _document_ object as well. However, the dictionary also states that the tab spec is _optional_, which is not true in reality. Given that the command without a tab spec compiles and fails completely silently, my guess is that it's a _bug_, and that the _intent_ was to execute in the front window's current tab by default.